# How do I use the Wicked::FIRST_STEP constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wizard, wicked-gem

I am not quite sure on how to use the `Wicked::FIRST_STEP` constant.

The way I understand the documentation I would think that it will point to the first step in the steps array, but what I actually get is the hardcoded string: "wicked_first" (as expected when looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/blob/b37366ff24c3c45ec9bfb782a95367399c68ed4e/lib/wicked.rb#L3)

Can somebody shed some light on how to use these constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used Wicked before, but from a cursory glance, it seems that this constant is supposed to be used with url helpers (see their [navigation test](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/blob/b37366ff24c3c45ec9bfb782a95367399c68ed4e/test/integration/navigation_test.rb)), or so:

```rb
def check_redirect_to_first_last!(step)
  redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first) if step.to_s == Wicked::FIRST_STEP
  redirect_to wizard_path(steps.last)  if step.to_s == Wicked::LAST_STEP
end
```

If you want to access the first step, I would rather look at [Wicked::Controller::Concerns::Steps](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/blob/b37366ff24c3c45ec9bfb782a95367399c68ed4e/lib/wicked/controller/concerns/steps.rb) and its `wizard_steps` or `steps_list` methods.